# Is there any alternative to flutter package call_log?

Tags: android, flutter

I've a flutter application which uses **call_log** flutter package to sync call logs between various devices. But currently I'm facing issues on latest android devices version 11. The error is:

> The plugin `call_log` uses a deprecated version of the Android
> embedding.
>
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to
> see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,
> consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove
> these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at the
> docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding

My app is crashing on latest android devices (version 11) and I'm not able to run on debug mode too.

What are the alternatives present? Shall I downgrade flutter version or wait for call_log package for new updates? My flutter version is 2.5.1. **Call_log** package version is 3.0.3.  It was last updated in May month. [call_log package](https://pub.dev/packages/call_log)

I'm just new in flutter so suggest me something I can do instantly to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/69475324/11445727 hope it may works for you.

Comment: Yes, at last I downgraded the flutter version and it resolved my issue. Thanks.