# The plugin `geocoder` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated, embedding, geocoder

When I run `pub get`, I face the following error:

`The plugin geocoder uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.`

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: when i run pub get i face the following problem problem. The problem of geocoder plugin,please help me to slove.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the latest flutter updated version 2.5. In my case I have downgraded my flutter version by command `flutter downgrade` and it shows an option of a downgraded flutter version and it resolves my error.

Answer (score 3):

GeoCoder package is deprecated for the newer flutter version. But there is this alternative you can use. This is compatible with newer flutter version and perfectly working fine.
Use this alternative : https://pub.dev/packages/geocode

Comment: Post version numbers so your answer keeps relevant over time. End of Review.

Answer (score 2):

Use This to Fix All Errors 
https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder2

```dart
import 'package:geocoder2/geocoder2.dart';
```

**Get Address**

```dart
    FetchGeocoder fetchGeocoder = await Geocoder2.getAddressFromCoordinates(
        latitude: 40.714224,
        longitude: -73.961452,
        googleMapApiKey: "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY");
    var first = fetchGeocoder.results.first;
    print(first.formattedAddress);
```

**Get Coordinates**

```
FetchGeocoder fetchGeocoder = await Geocoder2.getCoordinatesFromAddress(
        address: "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
        googleMapApiKey: "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY");
    var first = fetchGeocoder.results.first;
    print("${first.geometry.location.lat} , ${first.geometry.location.lng}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that plugin you could use the `Geocoding` plugin to find the address:

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```

Answer (score 0):

that simply means that the package you want to use is outdated and the flutter new update removed some functions that this package was using.

quick solution:

- outdate flutter by running this in the terminal 'flutter pub outdated' which I do not recommend
- or use an alternative for this package and make sure that this alternative is newly upgraded to be compatible with your flutter version

Comment: nice but my mentor using that plugin so I need this on for the project, Dear

Comment: you have to change the source code of the plugin then or as I told you to find an alternative

Comment: yup, but I'm new and hardy trying for my Start-Up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding), to achieve the same functionality. Please refer to it.